# Can't acces python variable inside function

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry for this beginner question but I'm not getting it right now.
I have a very simple python script, similar to this:

```
import os
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.title = "Test"
master.geometry("500x600")
input_str = Entry(master)
input_str.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
path = str(input_str.get())

def loadconfigs():
    print(path)

.......
.......
```

It would just print me an empty line of text everytime I call the function "function".
I'm sure this will be very easy to fix.
Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Comment: Which code are you executing?

Comment: Well, one thing -  you're overwriting `input` which is a python built-in function.

Comment: Thanks, oh sorry, it's not called input in the actual program, I changed it so it'll be easier to help here. I'll change it to sth. different.

Comment: Have you written mainloop in end of your code ?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: What do you mean by that? I'm executing the whole python file of which I posted the first lines here.

Comment: @P.Madhukar: Yes, I did. When writing 'path = "whatever"' under the "path = str(input_str.get())" it works fine and prints whatever in the console

Comment: I mean you're not showing us where you call that function, so it's hard to see what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you. figured out the problem. Obviously I have to get the string of path_input **after** calling the function!

Comment: You never call `loadconfigs()` therefore how can we know what the problem is? You need to provide examples that are **minimal**, **complete** and **verifiable**: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you didn't notice, this question has been solved by @jasonharper's answer. That's, why I didn't provide any extra information.

Answer (score 3):

You set the `path` variable ONCE, immediately after creating the associated Entry - there is no possibility whatsoever of it containing anything!  You need to defer calling `.get()` on the Entry until the button click or other event that requires something to be done with the typed value.

Comment: Well, that's very embarrassing and obvious. Thank you very much. Overlooked that!

Answer (score -4):

The easiest is just to use a global variable

```
import os
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.title = "Test"
master.geometry("500x600") 
input_str = Entry(master) 
input_str.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
global path
path = str(input_str.get())

def loadconfigs():
   global path
   print(path) l
```

Although global variables aren't ideal. You can't avoid them with tkinter unless you go object orientated.

Comment: The global statement doesn't do anything when you put it in the global scope, and it doesn't do anything in a function if you're not assigning something to the name in that function.

Comment: Also it's entirely possible to not use global variables or classes. You just need to handle parameter passing properly and carefully.